# Rails Devise allow Custom Fields in the Signup Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have two types of registration on on my website.

1. User
2. Host

There are two models related to Registration

```
users(id, name, is_host, ...)

hosts(company_name, user_id, status, ...)
```

Every Host is a User by default on the application. When the User signups on the website he has to enter the following fields

1. Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Phone Number

When a Host Signups he has to enter the following

1. Name
2. Email
3. Password
4. Phone Number
5. **Company Name**

On submitting the form as a host it should save the data in the User model and also set the `is_host` flag to `1` which other wise is `0` and then store the `company_name` in the `hosts` model.

**What i have done?**

I have installed devise and generated the migration tables and generated the scoped views.

**What i am trying to achieve?**

1. Add custom fields in the signup form, How to set the `strong parameter` for the User sign up form?
2. how to have a separate signup form for the same model and act as a registration for `HOSTS`

**views/users/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<h2>Sign up!!</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

**Server Error:**

```
Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name
```

Comment: Can you please show some code? At least showing view code of registration form would be a good start.

Comment: @Surya i have added the code above. is there any link i can refer to see how i can modify the same.

Answer (score 3):

Please look this example....

## we create the migration – nothing special here

```
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

## app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.slim

```
h2 Sign up

= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

    div
     = f.label :first_name
    br
     = f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true

    div
     = f.label :last_name
    br
     = f.text_field :last_name

    div
     = f.label :email
    br
     = f.email_field :email

    div
     = f.label :password
    br
     = f.password_field :password

    div
     = f.label :password_confirmation
    br
     = f.password_field :password_confirmation

    div
     = f.submit 'Sign up'

= render 'devise/shared/links'
```

## Customizing the RegistrationsController

```
def sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
end

def account_update_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
end
```

## registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params

    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)

  end

  def account_update_params

    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)

  end
end
```

## config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Comment: do i need to create a new file called registrations_conroller.rb in app/controllers/

Comment: In order to create your own custom registration controller for users with fallback to the original devise methods, I suggest you do the following:
1. create "users" folder in controllers folder 
2. create there registrations_controller.rb file, and define class there:                                                                                                                                   Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

Comment: can we have a quick chat?

Comment: the last two block of codes refers to the registration controller itself? why is it divided into two blocks?